# F# WSDL Type Provider and Confluence

Tags: f#, confluence, type-providers

When I use the WSDL Type provider to create a client for [Confluence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_%28software%29) SOAP service then I get all methods with (unit -> unit) signature.

```ml
#r "System.ServiceModel.dll"
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"
open System.ServiceModel
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

[<Literal>]
let ConfluenceServiceWsdl = "https://developer.atlassian.com/rpc/soap-axis/confluenceservice-v2?WSDL"
type ConfluenceService = Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.WsdlService<ConfluenceServiceWsdl>

let service = ConfluenceService.``Getconfluenceservice-v2``()

service.getPages;;
...
val it : (unit -> unit) = <fun:it@3-1>
```

but it should be something like 
`Vector<PageSummary> getPages(String token, String spaceKey)` - (from [Remote Confluence Methods](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Remote+Confluence+Methods) documentation)

What am I doing wrong? How to create full-functional service client? Is something wrong with WSDL?

P.S. Confluence SOAP WSDL was generated by [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [this issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-23963). As a workaround (a dirty one) you can do the following:

1. Specify LocalSchemaFile=.wsdlschema and ForceUpdate=false
2. Open .wsdlschema, fix messages that corresponds to faults and add corresponding elements

As a sample:

this

```
<wsdl:message name="VersionMismatchException">
    <wsdl:part name="fault" type="tns1:VersionMismatchException"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

will become

```
<wsdl:message name="VersionMismatchException">
    <wsdl:part name="fault" element="tns1:VersionMismatchException"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

and this

```
<complexType name="AlreadyExistsException">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="tns1:RemoteException">
             <sequence/>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

will be changed to

```
<complexType name="AlreadyExistsException">
    <complexContent mixed="false">
        <extension base="tns1:RemoteException">
            <sequence />
         </extension>
     </complexContent>
</complexType>
<element name="AlreadyExistsException" type="tns1:AlreadyExistsException"/>
```

Comment: I have corrected file and did as you said, but it does not help. [confluenceservice-v2.wsdlschema](https://gist.github.com/4550826)